# How to set logout url in django-registration?

Tags: python, django, django-registration

Log out works okay, but I can't set redirect logout url using django-registration.

In html:

`<h3> <a style="color:white" href="{%url 'logout' %}">"Logout"</a></h3>`

In settings.py:

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "accounts/logout"
```

I can access login page using `accounts/login` in browser, but it doesn't work for `accounts/logout`(Page not found.,but this page is in registration folder).

Comment: The `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL` is the url where requests are redirected after **logout** process, not a **logout link**

Comment: Sure, url used in LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL should be served in views.py and urls.py, but in registration this things are built-in

Answer (score 0):

yep, it's a url where User will be redirected right after logout.

Usually it's `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'`

try to click on your logout url now.

If you want to override logout function, I think you need to add new one

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Other URL patterns ...
    url(r'^accounts/logout/', some_view.custom_logout, name='django_registration_register'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django_registration.backends.one_step.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    # More URL patterns ...
]
```

Comment: "/" - is a home page, yep, It works as well as "accounts/login" page, but exactly logout won't work. Commenting this this line redirects correct, but to built-in page, not custom